# Allowing a test to run again C++

Tags: c++, pseudocode

I'm new to Stack Overflow and would just like to thank all the people that have unknowingly helped me so far. Anyhow, I'm currently writing the pseudocode for a program in which multiplication problems are generated for the user to answer. My professor wants this program to run until the user enters a sentinel value that would stop asking the user questions, and then display a report of how many questions they correctly answered and so forth.

All of that makes sense to me, and I'd probably be able to code most of that right now without struggling much. However, at the end of the direction sheet, it says "Your program should then repeat the process for another test taker". I'm not entirely sure how I'd go about doing that, since I have a 'while loop' running until the user terminates the program. The pseudocode is as follows:

```
BEGIN Lab 4 - Multiplication Program
 Mult_Num_1 = Random positive single digit number
 Mult_Num_2 = Random positive single digit number
 Calculate the product
 Display the multiplication problem, and sentinel value to quit
 User inputs an answer
 WHILE ( Answer != QUIT )
    IF ( Answer == Product )
        Inform user they are correct
        Add 1 to Correct_Counter
        Add 1 to Question_Counter
    ELSE
        Inform the user they are incorrect
        Display the correct answer
        Add 1 to Question_Counter
    END IF
    Calculate percentage of correct questions
    Clear screen
    Mult_Num_1 = Random positive single digit number
    Mult_Num_2 = Random positive single digit number
    Calculate the product
    Display the multiplication problem, and sentinel value to quit
    User inputs an answer
 END WHILE
 Display test report
END Lab 4 - Multiplication Program
```

I'd assume something needs to go after displaying the test report? I'm not entirely sure, but any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you for taking your time to look over this!

Comment: Also, I have asterisks in my actual program; I simply removed them to post here in order to more quickly post. My apologies.

Comment: Code that is run an arbitrary number of times is typically put in a named function.  Your pseudocode doesn't seem to recognize the existence of functions.

Comment: I would suggest putting what you currently have into a do while loop

Comment: Is there a TA you can talk to about your concerns? This needs mentoring not a Q&A, really.

Comment: I agree that the wording of the assignment is unclear, but you'd need to ask your teacher/TA about that! (It seems like implementing the `Answer != QUIT` condition is all that is required to satisfy the assignment?)